# I'm confused about python web application

Tags: python, django

I just learned , "python" programming and basic knowledge about css and html and java script and i was a "php" programmer before , I'm confused ,is it possible to program a web application just in python (a server side) with out using a framework like (django, flask , etc) or if i use django to develope , is it possible to put them both (django and pyhotn) in a single programm 
Regards

Comment: What do you mean, put "django and python" in a single program? Django *is* Python.

Comment: @ehsan hejazizadeh Request you to please google about web frameworks and read more about it. You will be able to learn there more than we can answer here. Django is a python based web framework.

Comment: I mean  , forget anything about django , how can i start web developing(server side) just by  python with out any framework?

Comment: You wouldn't do that. I mean, you could, but it would be very very silly. You'd have to learn all about the WSGI specification and how to handle the request/response process, write your own interface, etc. There's just no reason to do this. Use Flask.

Comment: Mr Roseman, so you mean i could learn django without no knowledge in pthoyn?

Comment: @ehsanhejazizadeh no you cannot " learn django without knowledge in pthoyn" - Django IS a Python framework.

Comment: But there's nothing to stop you learning both at the same time.

Comment: "is it possible to program a web application just in python" => yes of course, just any turing complete language will do actually - but "with out using a framework" you'll end up reinventing the squared wheel instead of using batllefield-tested code that already solves 99% of the chore issues and let you concentrate on your application itself.

Answer (score 0):

Django is built using Python therefore you'd not be able to build your Django web application without Python.

I suggest you to begin with the [Django Getting Started](https://www.djangoproject.com/start/) checklist to see if it is something that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you want to serve a web application and do something else in the very same process, sure. Start a thread and make your second thing-to-do a background thread. I'd consider it as a bad practice though. But you can try.

Otherwise, Django is Python.

And yes, theoretically, you can write a web application without Django or any framework. But you would need to write huge amounts of code. I don't think you're asking the question in this way but, just for making it clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a web application the way you're used to in PHP using Python by using the cgi module.

However, while cgi style web application is simple for one page application, this is considered very poor style in Python, it doesn't scale, it's somewhat weird and tedious (because it abuses stdin/stdout), and it's bad for performance (because it has to reload all modules every request). This style of writing application doesn't scale to larger, more complicated projects, although this is the only style that is really available in PHP, but it is partly the reason why most major PHP frameworks almost always advise you to write .htaccess rules that rewrites all request to a single file. The same problems plagues PHP, however in PHP, cgi style application is somewhat less painful because the language is optimised for this style of application, but it is also the reason why PHP have had to preload thousands of built in functions in the global namespace; as the language would be unbearable to use otherwise.

In Python, it's more common to use WSGI to talk to the webserver, but using WSGI is much more complicated than CGI, as WSGI is very low level and is primarily intended for framework developer rather than application developer, and that WSGI requires you to keep a persistent process running (this is in contrast to the new process for every request style of CGI). Most application developers are expected to instead use a web framework, as Python has a lot of frameworks suited for many different projects and sizes of applications.